# ModuleNotFoundError - Import module from specific directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following folder structure for my Python project (in Pycharm):

```
Tool
|___Script
      |___logs
      |___ tests
      |    |___setA
      |    |___setB
      |    |___setC
      |         |___testSetC.py
      |___ __init__.py
      |______script.py
```

and I'm trying to import methods defined in `script.py` in `testSetC.py`.

I have `from Script.script import *` at the top of `testSetC.py`and the script runs without any issues inside `Pycharm`. However, when I tried to run the same from the command line, it failed with the error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Script'`.

I poked around and found that Pycharm's run configuration automatically adds the `Tool` directory to `PYTHONPATH` essentially masking the error.

What is the correct way to do this without manually amending `sys.path` in every test script? It looks hackish IMO.

Comment: There is no _correct_ way to do that. You have to tell your Python interpreter where to look for the `Script` package if you want it imported by scripts outside of the directory holding that package (which gets automatically appended to the path). If you don't do it before the run, you have to alter `sys.path` at runtime.

Comment: Thank You. I moved the tests folder under `Tools`, and added the following: `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))))`.

Comment: You should use proper relative qualifiers instead of multi-level split on the file's directory: `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir, os.pardir)))`,

Comment: I needed another `os.pardir` in the `os.path.join` with the new layout, but I get the point now. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it!